# Create table with one header and then rows and columns below

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to make a table with one row (header for all columns) and then with rows and cols below header (just a regular table after the header). I have something like this for now on:

```
<table style="margin: auto;" border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col align="left">
        <col align="right">
        <col align="right">
        <col align="right">
        <col align="right">
    <thead style="background: #F0F0F0" colspan="6" scope="colgroup">
        <tr>
            <th>header
    <thead style="background: #F0F0F0">
        <tr>
            <th>a 
            <th> a 
            <th> a 
            <th> a <br> b 
            <th> a 
            <th> a
</table>
```

but now, 'header' is in the first column only and I would like it to be stretched for all columns.

Comment: hmm... I'd consider fixing the html first. You miss a lot of closing tags, that's a first.

Comment: @giorgio: should I close `TH` tag?

Comment: you should close every tag :) The colgroup, tr, AND th. And although you _could_ use multiple theads, it's more logical to use multiple tr's inside one thead. And user lowercase characters for tag names, it's better readable (uppercase is really oldskool, like in books of 1994).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `colspan` on the `th` tag and not on the `thead`

```
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th colspan="6">Head</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JsSz4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,it works fine.

just did few changes to your code.

```
<table style="margin: auto; border:1">
        <colgroup>
            <col align="left">
            <col align="right">
            <col align="right">
            <col align="right">
            <col align="right">
            <col align="right">
            </colgroup>
            <thead style="background: #F0F0F0"  scope="colgroup">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="6">
                        header
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead style="background: #F0F0F0">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        a
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        a
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        a
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        a
                        <br>
                        b
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        a
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        a
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="background: #FFFFFF">
            </tbody>
         </table>
```

Comment: colgroup should enclose the `col` tags, not the whole table... Like this: `<colgroup><col>...</colgroup> <thead>... etc.`

Comment: thanx @giorgio , did the necessary changes.

Comment: that's much better :) now if you fix the css in the table tag (`border=1` => `border:1`) I can give you an upvote without the wrath of the www gods falling upon me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<TABLE style=\margin: auto;\ border=1><COLGROUP><COL align="left"><COL align=right><COL align="right"><COL align="right"><COL align=right>
<THEAD style="background: #F0F0F0" colspan="6" scope="colgroup"><TR> <TH colspan="6">header
<THEAD style="background: #F0F0F0"><TR> <TH>a <TH> a <TH> a <TH> a <br> b <TH> a <TH> a
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<TABLE style=\margin: auto;\ border=1>
<COLGROUP><COL align=left><COL align=right><COL align=right><COL align=right><COL align=right>
    <THEAD style=\background: #F0F0F0 \ colspan=\6\ scope=\colgroup\><TR> <TH colspan="6">header
    <THEAD style=\background: #F0F0F0 \><TR> <TH>a <TH> a <TH> a <TH> a <br> b <TH> a <TH> a
    <TBODY style=\background: #FFFFFF\>
    </TABLE>
```